# Can I resume a job in the background and redirect its standard output to a file?

Tags: bash, jobs

I have stopped a job by pressing `Ctrl-z`. Can I resume the job with `bg`, yet have the output redirected to a log file instead of stdout? Doing the following:

```
bg > log.txt
```

Only writes the initial printed line (e.g. `[1]+ <<job_name>> &`) to the log file.

Comment: This very same question has been asked among the network plenty of times, one is https://stackoverflow.com/q/593724/991073

Comment: Although SO is not unix.SE, I don't think it's worth duplicating the answers again here. (meta: what to do with cross site dups https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4708/what-to-do-with-cross-site-duplicates)

Comment: And if someone really come up with a novel solution, they should, instead of spattering around here, consider contributing to the one canonical thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an external tool for that. Check for example:

[**reredirect**](https://github.com/jerome-pouiller/reredirect/)

> reredirect is a utility for taking an existing running program and attaching its outputs (standard output and error output) to files or another process.

or [**dupx**](https://www.isi.edu/%7Eyuri/dupx/)

> Dupx is a simple *nix utility to redirect standard output/input/error of an already running process.
>
> Dupx is currently implemented as a simple shell script that drives
> GDB.